# OSX IIS Log File Viewer

Tags: iis, logging, mac, mac-osx

Are there any log file viewers available for OSX? Or, off-the-shelf programs that can be configured to parse IIS files.

Perhaps something int he MacPorts tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a Console.app inside of /Applications/Utilities. If you prefer more "advanced" tool, you can fire up a Terminal.app and use `tail -f` and `grep`

Comment: Btw, there is an Apache on OSX (instead of IIS)